# excel error: invalid or unqualified error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

```
Sub Macro5()
    '
    ' Macro5 Macro
    '
    
    '
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("g:\Work\EU Personal Assignment.xlsx")
        Range("O2:R2").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Dashboard_for_Roshan.xlsm").Activate
        Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Windows("EU Personal Assignment.xlsx").Activate
        Range("A2").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
    
    
        Windows("Dashboard_for_Roshan.xlsm").Activate
        Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Windows("EU Personal Assignment.xlsx").Activate
        Range("AC2").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
    
        Windows("Dashboard_for_Roshan.xlsm").Activate
        Range("F65536").End(xlUp).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    
    
    Call .wbk.Close(False) <- i get the error here 
    
    
End Sub
```

Prior to the excel `End(xlUp)`, I was using

```
Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Select
```

but I was unable to paste data using this.

Edit: the error was an extra `.` before .wbk
but now it replaces the previous row data, whereas I want it to paste data below the last used row.
any advice?

Comment: the posted code is irrelevant to what you are asking. Try `Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlup).ROw+1).Value = "last cell + 1"`

Comment: hello mehow,
 actually this was the original error i was getting which i fixed.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To paste below the data you need to select the row 1 below your data before you paste

To use the same method as you try:

```
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Or as an alternative method try:

```
Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Select
```

To fix your error try using this:

```
wbk.Close
```